# How can I find a function that is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ with its derivative also but its limit tends to zero?

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces

I am trying to find for a function that would full-fill these conditions below:
 $$f \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$$
$$f' \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$$

but its $\lim_{t \to \infty}=0$.

I've tried to find a function which dominator is larger than nominator but usually these are improper integrals and do not converge!

Can somebody suggest any function? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What about $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$?

Comment: @PhoemueX Thans a lot!

Comment: It would be more interesting to find one whose limit didn't exist.'

Comment: I am with @zhw on this and suspect that you have not reproduced the problem correctly.  Otherwise simply take $f(x)=f'(x)=0$ and you are done.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson Idea in fact is to show that every function that fulfils that two conditions above then it implies limit of function tends to zero.

Comment: but I asked for an example of that

Comment: I see now I made an error above in thinking there could be a function satisfying the two conditions without $f(x) \to 0.$

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I wanted only an example in my question! But if you can provide a proof of that that would be perfect!

Comment: Still not completely sure what all the hypotheses are.  If you want *one* example of such a situation then $f=f'=0$ works, but that can't be what you want.  On the other hand these conditions don't seem very strong:  take $f$ as a continuous singular function so that $f'=0$.  I don't see any reason why $f$ would have to have a zero limit at $\infty$.

Comment: And finally (perhaps finally since there is a whole lot wrong with this problem):  the assumption that $f$ is only in $L_1(\mathbb{R})$ would allow us to change the values on each of the integers so as to mess with the possibility that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.  I am assuming that $f'$ is not required to exist *everywhere*?  If you do assume that $f$ is differentiable everywhere then $f$ would be absolutely continuous on each interval and you can prove that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.  See my attempt at an interpretation which permits $f'$ to exist only a.e..

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I think we can assume "differentiable" means "differentiable everywhere". In that case the two conditions imply $f\to 0.$

Comment: @zhw I was sure that that was your interpretation.  Normally though a statement like $f'\in L_1(\mathbb R)$ wouldn't require everywhere differentiable.  Melina might let us know whether the actual text of the problem had an assumption of *everywhere*.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I am sorry that I have been offline but there is assumed only f is continuously differentiable! Thanks a lot for your effort... Really I appreciated what you have done below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardest part of this problem has been determining what the problem is.  Here is
my guess at the problem and hints for an answer.  Melina will let us know if this is relatively close.

> **Problem**.  Supose that $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is a continuous
>   function for which both $f$ and $f'$ belong to $L_1([0,\infty)$.
>
> *Part (a)*  Show that it is not necessarily the case that $f(x)\to 0$ as
>   $x\to \infty$.
>
> *Part (b)*  Show that, if we also assume that $f$ is *absolutely
>   continuous,* then  it is true that $f(x)\to 0$ as $x\to \infty$.

*Hint for (b)*:  Let $\epsilon>0$.  Then there is a $T$ so that
$$|f(s)-f(t)| = \left| \int_s^t f'(t)\,dt \right| < \epsilon$$
for all $T \leq s <t$.  From that and the fact that
$f$   belongs to $L_1([0,\infty)$ 
one can deduce that $f(x)\to 0$ as
  $x\to \infty$.

*Hint for (a)*:  There is a standard and well-known example of a nonegative, continuous function $f:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$  for which $f(n)=1$ for each $n=1,2,3, ...$ and yet the integral $\int_0^\infty f(t)\,dt$ exists (either as a Lebesgue integral or as an improper Riemann integral --which amounts to the same thing here).  Modify that example so that the function $f$ is singular, i.e., so that $f'=0$ almost everywhere.

**Note 1**.: As @zhw points out there is the possibility (probability?)  that the original version of the problem assumed that $f$ is *everywhere* differentiable, in which case (since we know $f'$ is integrable) we can use part (b) of the problem.

**Note 2.** Melina has confirmed that her assignment assumed even more, namely that $f$ is to be *continuously differentiable*.  This reduces the problem to an elementary analysis problem and all integrals can be interpreted as Riemann or improper Riemann integrals.  The indication that $f$ and $f'$ belong to $L_1(\mathbb R)$ does not normally suggest that $f'$ would have to exist everywhere.  We also do not need to mention absolute continuity (although it wouldn't be incorrect to do so).  If $f'$ is everywhere continuous then the hint for (b) just uses the baby fundamental theorem of the calculus stated for continuous functions.